# wordpress multisite wp_update_nav_menu_item returns $menu_item_db_id but does not show in menu

Tags: php, navigation, wordpress

I have a strange problem when using the wp_update_nav_menu_item function in a multisite installation.

It normally works when I execute this from within wp-admin.  However, now I've been tasked with writing a handler script to auto-create a site, add a number of default pages, add a menu and populate the menu with those pages.

Here is the code in question:

```
$miid = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
'menu-item-title' => $post['post_title'],
'menu-item-object' => 'page',
'menu-item-object-id' => $pid,
'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
'menu-item-parent-id' => $navParentID,
'menu-item-position' => $post['menu_order']));
```

I've ensured that all of the values passed in to the function are correct and match with those which would be passed in when I call this function from within wp-admin dashboard.

The blog gets created successfully, as do the default pages, and the menu.  When this executes it does return a `$menu_item_db_id` value indicating it worked successfully but nothing has actually been added to the menu and calling something like `print_r(wp_get_nav_menu_object($menu_id));` returns nothing.

When I call the same exact function with the same exact inputs from a page within wp-admin everything works fine.

I've considered that perhaps the current blog context was not set correctly and have used this snippet to validate that I'm in the correct blog:

```
//Ensure we're updating the correct blog
$blogid = get_current_blog_id();
switch_to_blog($blogid);
echo get_current_blog_id()."<br/>";
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I've had exactly the same problem..
The solution was to create item and menu relationship for each item :

```
wp_set_object_terms($item_id, $menu_id, 'nav_menu');
```

For some reason it was not created in `wp_update_nav_menu_item`